# Automating Configuration of devcontainer.json in GitHub Codespaces with Frequently Used VSCode Extensions

Tags: automation, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, github-codespaces, devcontainer

I am utilizing GitHub Codespaces with VSCode Remote to streamline my development workflow. However, every time I create a new Codespace, I find myself manually configuring the devcontainer.json file to include the VSCode extensions that I frequently use. This manual setup is time-consuming and repetitive.

Is there a way to automate the process of configuring devcontainer.json to include my preferred set of VSCode extensions? Ideally, I would like to have a pre-configured devcontainer.json file that automatically adds the extensions I frequently use whenever I create a new Codespace.

**Key Points:**

- I need an automated way to configure devcontainer.json with my
  frequently used VSCode extensions.
- The automation should occur during the creation of a new GitHub Codespace.
- The goal is to simplify and expedite the setup process for my development environment.